# Can gdb break on/dprintf on/specify location as: return from specified function?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm debugging some C code. I want to dprintf a message when a certain function returns, regardless of how it actually returns, and even if it returns without hitting a literal return statement (for example, when a void function reaches the end of its body). I understand I could write e.g. `dprintf name_of_fn:13, "message %d\n", param` or something for a function whose body was 13 lines long. But this sucks if I'm actively editing the function, since I might be changing the length of its body.

Is this possible? Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks homies

Answer (score 3):

It is not easily possible, but it can be done.  It requires either a trick or some Python programming.

The trick is old-school.  What you do is make a breakpoint at the start of the function, then set a temporary breakpoint at the return location that does what you want.  For example:

```
break function
commands
  up-silently
  tbreak
  commands
    printf "hi!\n"
    cont
  end
  cont
end
```

One thing to note here is that `tbreak` without arguments will stop at the current PC -- which in the `up` frame is the return location.

This will work pretty well in many situations -- but not all.  In particular, if you are using `next` to step through the code, and you step over a call to `function` (even one somewhere far down the stack), gdb will act as though you typed `cont`, and will forget to stop for the `next`.  (Also I have a vague recollection that in some versions of gdb you can't nest `commands` like this.  So there may be that to contend with as well.)

This `next` quirk, FWIW, is one of the things that `dprintf` was meant to deal with more nicely.

With Python scripting, you can do better -- you can make it work correctly with `next` as well.  The way to do this is to subclass `gdb.FinishBreakpoint`, and, in the code above, create an instance of your subclass.

Your subclass can do all the actions you like.  In your case, you would implement the `stop` method to print the message you want, and then return `False`.  This is what will let the finish breakpoint not cause a user-visible stop, and thus make `next` work properly.

One other nice thing about `FinishBreakpoint` is that you have access to the function's return value.

Comment: This is interesting, but seems way too complicated. I'm inclined to complain to gdb maintainers (e.g. to one Tom Tromey) that this ought to be a primitive location specifier along with function-name:label-name and suchlike. Do you think it would clash too much with gdb's source-orientation?

I mean, I understand that I could dig into gdb scripting and configuration, and I'm sure it would pay dividends for a heavy user, but I don't actually debug with gdb that much.

Comment: Yeah, I think a simpler way to do this would be very nice.  Maybe it could be done in Python, though I think you'd need some hacks to make the `commands` apply to the finish breakpoint.  And there's the question of which breakpoint a `cond` should apply to.  Also, FWIW I no longer work on gdb.

Answer (score -2):

here is a simple example, from: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dynamic-Printf.html

The referenced page goes into all the details of using dprintf with gdb

```
      (gdb) set dprintf-style call
      (gdb) set dprintf-function fprintf
      (gdb) set dprintf-channel mylog
      (gdb) dprintf 25,"at line 25, glob=%d\n",glob

      Dprintf 1 at 0x123456: file main.c, line 25.

      (gdb) info break
      1       dprintf        keep y   0x00123456 in main at main.c:25
              call (void) fprintf (mylog,"at line 25, glob=%d\n",glob)
              continue
      (gdb)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, IMO, sorry.